# How to read this list string from txt file

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have this list string in text file:

```
[array([21998.], dtype=float32), array([648.], dtype=float32), array([305.], dtype=float32), array([182.], dtype=float32)]
```

How to read array values?

The below code I have tried

```
with open(datPath+'histo1.txt', 'r') as file:
   hist1 = np.array(eval(file.read())) # read list string and convert to array
print(hist1)
```

But it gives me error:

```
name 'float32' is not defined
```

Comment: You can define `array` and `float32` using `from numpy import array, float32`. Then you only need to do `hist1 = eval(file.read())`.  A more fundamental question, perhaps, is whether it is safe to use `eval`. It can cause your python session to execute arbitrary code. The question is whether you control the input so that this is not a problem, or whether you will be processing externally provided input, where you may need to take a more careful approach for security reasons.  If the latter, you have a much more complex problem to solve.

Comment: Your comment helps too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide mapping for array and float32 with it's respective functions and pass it to `eval`. If you have multiple lines in your file, loop over then read & convert each line at a time.

```
import numpy as np

string = "[array([21998.], dtype=float32), array([648.], dtype=float32), array([305.], dtype=float32), array([182.], dtype=float32)]"

results = eval(string, {"array": np.array, "float32": np.float32})

print(results )
# [array([21998.], dtype=float32), array([648.], dtype=float32), array([305.], dtype=float32), array([182.], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: or do `from numpy import array, float32`

Comment: @bsekirarski see my general comments regarding `eval`, that I've posted as a comment on your question. The answer might be yes, it is fine to use `eval` in this situation, but it is a consideration that you need to bear in mind. (We can't decide that for you.)